# Geometric nodes - how can I change the scale of different nodes at the same time? without losing the scale ratio between them

Tags: node-editor

Geometric nodes - how can I change the scale of different nodes at the same time? without losing the scale ratio between them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Math nodes transforming a single input:

[image]

Comment: Thank You!!!! it works))